# Does anyone know how to reduce data transfer out charges on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I created a t3.micro EC2 instance on aws being costed at an hourly rate of $0.0065/hr. It's got 2 vCPUs and 1 GiB Memory. I manged to run a 128 tick CS:GO server on it, but the data transfer out charges are killing it. The estimated cost of this server per month is around $43, considering I only play 5 scrims (5v5 competitives) per day, and data transfer out alone costs me $38 in this case. However, some individuals are offering me a server for as low as $10 per month. What am I doing wrong? How do they do it?

Comment: You can save up to 75% if you get reserved instances if you know you will use this instance for long.

Comment: That would only reduce instance running cost not the data transfer out cost, right?

Comment: yes. Not sure if you can do something about data transfer in your case. But its seems a lot of data. Are you sure your CS:GO generates so much traffic?

Comment: With 10 people on server, each consuming 250 MB of data approx each match... I think yes.

Comment: $43/(5*30). That's less than 30 cents per battle. Not a bad deal for the entertainment. :-)

Comment: Some provide it for $10 unlimited matches, but idk how is that possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider moving from Amazon EC2 to **Amazon Lightsail**.

Lightsail has **pricing plans that include volumes of Data Transfer traffic** and it is designed for people who just want to launch a small number of virtual computers (eg WordPress instances) rather than configure a whole cloud infrastructure.

See: [Amazon Lightsail Pricing | Virtual Private Server (VPS) | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/)

Comment: wow, i always sort of wrote off lightsail for power users but there is definitely great costs savings to had there, thanks for sharing.